# Elasticsearch set max count for founded doc

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I mean elastic currently draws me totalElements (all founded docs), but I needs to limit the search to 10000 founded docs.

I expected such a result for example:

```
totalElements = 3031203120
founded = 10000 // here maximum is 10 000
```

if totalElements <= 10 000

```
totalElements = 100 // here maximum is 10 000
founded = 100 // here maximum is 10 000
```

Is there a possibility for do that? And another question if such an option exists, it is automatically be converted value TotalPages etc.

I want solutions using native search query.

I hope that as you understand what I mean if you do not ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terminate_after parameter. for eg:

```
GET /products/_search
{
    "query": {"match_all": {}}, 
    "terminate_after": 100
}
```

This will limit the the number of hits in each shard to 100.

So if you have 5 shards you will get a maximum of 500 hits.